# Unable to create an object of type 'DataContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a solution with multiple projects. I have one project named "Persistence" where I have the code for the db context. I have a domain project for entities and I have an API project that will be used from the front end application.

My DataContext.cs file inside the Persistence project looks like this:

```
using System;
using Domain;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Persistence
{
    public class DataContext: DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options){}

        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }


        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
                @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=testDB;Integrated Security=True");
        }
    }
}
```

When CD inside the persistence project and running this command:

```
dotnet ef migrations add initcreate -s ..\API\
```

I receive this error:

> Unable to create an object of type 'DataContext'. For the different
>   patterns supported at design time, see
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

I am still new to entity framework and .net in general, any help and guidance is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You can refer to this link ：https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/issues/1080

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because to generate migrations you need either:

1. A DbContext with a default constructor (that is, a parameterless
   constructor)
2. Being able to get the DbContext from ApplicationServices (that is, Dependency Injection)
3. A design-time factory that returns a properly configured DbContext.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Its 3 years old questions XD. but I just got this same issue today.

Found out i need to set the type of my DataContext Class on DbContextOptions.

> public DataContext(DbContextOptions<**DataContext**> options) :
> base(options)

So the result is here:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<VideoGame> VideoGames { get; set; }
}
```

*of course you also need add AddDbContext on Program.cs/Startup.cs